# Ckeditor5. The editor replaces the first tag with h1. How to disable it?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5

The editor automatically adds or changes the tags in the first line to the H1 header tag. How can this be fixed or disabled?
That is, I have the p tag first in the text, the editor formats it to H1 himself.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove "Title" from Editor.builtinPlugins

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this.  The problem with this, is that it you loose the ability to use the h1 after.  It's a weird setup

```
    DecoupledDocumentEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#' + id ), {
          //removePlugins: ['Title']
        } )
        .then( editor => {

            editor.enableReadOnlyMode( id );

        } )
        .catch( error => {
            console.error( error );
        } );
```